# CSS :before breaks CSS rules following it

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have this in my styles.css file:

```
.widget_categories ul li a:before {
  content:"\f105";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:5px;
  color:#00BCD4;
}​
```

Weirdly, this breaks any CSS rule immediately following it, yet it looks perfectly fine to me. Can anyone see what the issue is?

Comment: What's the next rule? perhaps that's the one breaking it

Comment: I can't reconstruct it: http://jsfiddle.net/pwha2eth/

Comment: What do you mean "breaks any rule following it"? Breaks how? Does this particular rule 'work'? But the ones following aren't applied?

Comment: @JayMee - Sorry I might not have been clear. When I say breaks it, some rules following this don't work at all, as though they don't exist. I have tried this with different rules and it affects random ones. When I place the above :before rule at the end of the CSS file, everything works fine. One of the rules that doesn't work when it is placed after this is a simple footer { font-size:14px;}. I have no idea why this wouldn't work when it comes after it.

Comment: can you re-create in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closing } appears to be some funny character. Deleting and replacing fixed it in the validator: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

*Be sure to remove the newline before it as well

Comment: Awesome spot! This worked. Not sure how that weird character creeped in there...

Comment: Glad it helped! Personally I've had these sorts of issues appear when working in more than one OS or language environment. The above W3 validator has saved me many times by pointing out the exact line/column of something it doesn't understand.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of using a validator! I'll remember this for the future :)